# Copy all files and folders inside specific folder in batch file

Tags: batch-file, copy

i have a batch script that i want it to copy everything inside a specific folder to another but it only copy files it doesn't copy the sub folders.
thanks in advance

Here is how im copying the inside of the folder:

```
 xcopy /s %FILETOZIP% %TEMPDIR%
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using XCOPY, the parameters should be at the end:

```
XCOPY source [destination] [options]
```

If any folders are empty and you want to include them, you will need the /E parameter instead.

Try the following to capture the entire directory structure:

```
xcopy %FILETOZIP% %TEMPDIR% /s /e
```

Comment: Thanks it does the same thing :( @Erebos

Comment: It worked, it doesnt copy the empty folders but that not needed thanks